# Compile google/protobuf with ExternalProject_Add - Android

Tags: android, c++, cmake, protocol-buffers

I did create this bash script for compiling `protobuf` for Android but I don't want to have a separate build script just for this, I want it integrated in Android build in `CMakeLists.txt`.

This is the script that I have for compiling `protobuf` for Android:

```sh
export NDK=~/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620
export TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
export TARGET=x86_64-linux-android
export API=26

export AR=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/llvm-ar
export CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET$API-clang
export AS=$CC
export CXX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET$API-clang++
export LD=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/ld
export RANLIB=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/llvm-ranlib
export STRIP=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/llvm-strip

export CFLAGS="-fpie -fpic -O3"
export CXXFLAGS="-fpie -fpic -O3"
export CPPFLAGS="-fpie -fpic -O3"
export LDFLAGS="-llog -fPIC"

../protobuf-3.19.0/configure --host $TARGET --disable-shared --with-pic --with-gnu-ld
make -j$(nproc)
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(ANDROID_CMAKE_ARGS
        -DANDROID_ABI=${ANDROID_ABI}
        -DANDROID_PLATFORM=${ANDROID_PLATFORM}
        -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
        -DANDROID_NDK=${ANDROID_NDK}
        -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}
        -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE}
        -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM}
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
        -G${CMAKE_GENERATOR})

ExternalProject_Add(
  protobuf-external
  PREFIX protobuf
  URL ${PROTOBUF_TAR_GZ}
  BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/protobuf
  CMAKE_ARGS
    "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}"
    "-Dprotobuf_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF"
    "-Dprotobuf_BUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF"
    "-Dprotobuf_WITH_ZLIB:BOOL=OFF"
    "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}"
  SOURCE_SUBDIR cmake
  BUILD_ALWAYS 1
  STEP_TARGETS build
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

EXternalProject_Get_Property(protobuf-external source_dir)

include_directories(${source_dir}/src)
link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/protobuf)
```

In `.cxx/` only the folders are getting created but not getting compiled, what exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the shell script you build Protobuf using `configure` (Autotools). `ExternalProject_Add` by default builds with `cmake`. These could be different builds.

Comment: I can use `configure` too but they don't have it on the archive. It does compile on my linux machine if I don’t plug the Android args. It generates the same output